# Solution For Single-Master HA MySQL on Kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, percona, galera

I'm looking for a solution to deploy HA MySQL cluster on kubernetes. The main feature must be automatic fail-over (being resilient to crashing master pod).
There is two main types of solutions.

1. Multi-Master Clusters like Percona XtraDB Cluster. These solutions has some limitations that will make some problems.
2. Single-Master Cluster with observer pod and a Proxy. The best-known solution I found is Orchestrator, and by now it is a dead project. I didn't found any other solutions that has been widely used.

I'll be so glad to know which solution can solve my problem.

I've tried Percona Operator for kubernetes and it has some limitations. I've also tested mysql operator for kubernetes and it has some bugs. Galera Cluster for MariaDB is not resilient to crashing more than half of MySQL instances.

Comment: I don't know of any solution that is resilient against more than half the instances crash at the same time. If you need that level of resilience, then you probably need to burn your database onto a CDROM. It will be read-only, but very resilient. (j/k)

Comment: You can run XtraDB Cluster (or Galera) in single-master mode.  With it, you could deploy 5 nodes one in each of 5 datacenters if you must protect against 2 failures (of server or datacenter.

Comment: I suggest that software failures and hacker attacks and rogue employees are more of a danger than two hardware failures.